# Как сделать так, чтобы сервер отправлял клиенту команду в назначенное кодом время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокеты

Я начал изучать мир сокетов. Мне хотелось бы узнать у экспертов, каким образом можно написать код для того, чтобы сервер отправлял клиенту в назначенное время команду, в ответ на которую клиент выполнял бы определённые действия: например, открывал бы какой-нибудь файл по команде от сервера "open", которая отправляется в режиме расписания. Прошу помочь! Или хотя бы посоветуйте литературу, в которой подробно описывается работоспособность сокетов... Не оставайтесь равнодушными!)

Comment: Сокеты всего лишь передают байты туда-сюда и не имеют никакого отношения ни к файлам, ни к командам — это две никак не связанные задачи. Связать байтики с командами — это третья отдельная задача. Определитесь, с какой из этих трёх задач у вас трудности, и конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: Я именно это и хочу сделать. Сервер будет отправлять клиенту пакет данных в определённое время. Клиент будет принимать этот пакет данных и, согласно скрипту, который будет у клиента, выполнять определённое количество постоянных действий, без переменных значений.

Comment: Вот и хорошо, а теперь расскажите, что конкретно из написанного не получается

Comment: Ах да, я сразу не заметил, но выполнение чего-либо по расписанию — это четвёртая задача, не связанная с предыдущими тремя. В общем, вопрос слишком общий